# Writing a HelloWorld with Modules and Classes

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I am using RubyMine IDE so maybe this is because I don't know how to use it! but here is what I have:
A module named MyFirstModule  that has a method named say_hello

```
module MyFirstModule
  def say_hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end
end
```

And also a class that wrote it like this:

```
require 'MyFirstModule'
class ModuleTester

  include MyFirstModule

end

mt = ModuleTester.new
mt.say_hello
```

Then I run the program through IDE and this is the error I get:

> /Users/Jony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby -e
>   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
>   /Users/Jony/RubymineProjects/Rubyist/play_one.rb
>   /Users/Jony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- MyFirstModule (LoadError)     from
>   /Users/Jony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require'     from /Users/Jony/RubymineProjects/Rubyist/play_one.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from -e:1:in`load'     from -e:1:in `'

Comment: Include your directory structure in the post.

Comment: @LoganSerman : Two .rb files called play_one.rb that the class is in it, and the MyFirstModule.rb that the module is in it.

Answer (score 1):

The require statement uses file names without the rb, not class/module identifiers. 
My guess is you need to change your require line to:

require 'my_first_module'

You'll also want to check your load path.